# how we open activity when app is closed in android

Tags: java, android, firebase, kotlin, chat

I used calling functionality in my application. when the app is in the foreground then the application is working well. but when the app is in the background then how to open incoming call Activity in android. When a push notification is appeared then open incoming call Activity in android. how to perform this task?

Comment: Please use a high-priority `Notification`.

Comment: If it's a call, then using `setFullScreenIntent` on your notification builder is the standard UX design on newer androids (since api 29). In other cases you may acquire display over other apps (aka SYSTEM_OVERLAY) permission.

Comment: The safest way is to try to show the activity via intent and also show a notification, but remember to hide the notification in onCreate() of your activity

Answer (score 2):

Android 10 (API level 29) and higher place restrictions on when apps can start activities when the app is running in the background. These restrictions help minimize interruptions for the user and keep the user more in control of what's shown on their screen.

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts

Comment: But how to open Activity from background to foreground in android

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/navigation

Comment: This link is not helpful for me. please suggest to me any other answer.

Comment: Thanks Mohammad! it works like churm

Answer (score 1):

You have to call it in firebase messaging service.

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, IncomingCallActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra(Constants.KEY_FIRST_NAME, firstName);
                    intent.putExtra(Constants.KEY_LAST_NAME, lastName);
                    intent.putExtra(Constants.KEY_EMAIL, email);
                    intent.putExtra(Constants.KEY_ID, id);
                    intent.putExtra(Constants.KEY_DP, dp);
                    intent.putExtra(Constants.CALL_TYPE, callType);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    this.startActivity(intent);
```

in manifest

```
 <activity
            android:name="IncomingCallActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:showOnLockScreen="true"
            android:showWhenLocked="true"
            android:turnScreenOn="true" />



 <service
            android:name="MessagingService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

Answer (score 0):

Notifications may have a pending intent attached. This pending intent may start an activity. See [Notification.Builder.setContentIntent()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder#setContentIntent(android.app.PendingIntent))

Answer (score 0):

You can add a Pending Intent to your notification, so when user clicks on it, your intent will be launched.

To create a Pending Intent you should:

1. Create a normal Intent to your destination Activity.

   `val goActivity = Intent(context, Activity::class.java)`
2. Create a Pending Intent passing a context, a request code to identify the Pending Intent, your normal Intent and a flag to configure the way your Intent is launched.

   `val goActivityPending = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, pendingIntentCode, goActivity, PendingIntent.FLAG_NEW_TASK)`
3. Add your Pending Intent to your notification builder with method `setContentIntent`.

   `val notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(context, channelId) .setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.notificationTitle)) .setContentText(context.getString(R.string.notificationContent)) .setContentIntent(goActivityPending)`

That's it! When you click the notification, your activity will be oppened. You can also use `addAction()` to add buttons to your notification with different Pending Intents.

If you want to know more about Intent flags, read this: [Pending Intent Flags](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent#constants)